# Can I power Ardiuno using buck converter IC 3485 or any other buck circuit?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

A buck circuit lowers the voltage by generating pulses at a certain duty cycle. Is it okay to give this pulsing voltage to Arduino? Can Arduino work normally with this?

I have 12V battery and I want 6V from that.

Comment: I had the same confusion just like you. I thought that the output would have a 12v peak (when the PWM pulse is high) and 0v (when the pulse is low) if you use 12v input. But that is not the case. The PWM output will have a 12v peak and it will be a square wave, but there is an inductor which will smooth the PWM output. The output will have ripples, but it won't be a square wave like the PWM. If you increase the inductor value and switching frequency, it will further smooth the ripple. The following video helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCPEERuV0O8 , Please watch till the end.

Comment: Also, check out this small video for comparing the PWM output and the back converter output. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I62Yztl-bDQ

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with LM3485 or any other switching buck controller, you will need a bunch of external components, but this will give you really good power efficiencies (probably more than 90%, if implemented correctly). However if you want a simple solution, I mean if you don't want to mess up with a lot of external components (e.g. inductors, capacitors, diodes, FETS) you can just use a linear regulator with 6 V output regulation.

As a choice for linear regulator, I can suggest using MC7806 (http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC7800-D.PDF), which will give you 6 V constant output voltage easily, or I can suggest using LT1086 (http://www.linear.com/product/LT1086) which can give you 5 V constant output easily or an adjustable output which you can set to 6 V. However notice that, when you are using a linear regulator your efficiency will not be very good. For example, if you want to make a 6 V output from 12 V input, your efficiency will be approximately Vout/Vin = 6 V/12 V =  0.5 = 50%, which means half of the power your battery supplies will be dissipated as heat, e.g. will be wasted.

Also, besides these, you can just use the 12 V battery output to directly power your Arduino board through its power jack, which means you would not need to reduce 12 V into 6 V, if it was only for powering your board.

Comment: if 12v is directly connected to ardiuno, its 5v regulator heats very fast.

Answer (score 0):

How much current does the 6v load require?  If it is a few mA, why not use a  [resistive voltage divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)? or You could use a [6v zener diode.](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/4271-1n5233btr-6v-0-5w-silicon-unidirectional-voltage-regulator-diode-do-35.html) You can use the Arduino to create pulses that activate a MOSFET at whatever duty cycle you need, having the mosfet control the 12v battery into the resistive divider or the zener.  This will give you the 6v you need from the 12v battery with pulse control from the Arduino.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fONkX0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit R2 will need to be selected to limit current to the load.  The selected zener is 6v.
The MOSFET should be a TTL (5v) gate type.
And a gate resistor R3 should be determined according to the data sheet for the MOSFET you use.
The output pin should be of the 5v(HIGH) type.

Comment: I may have misread the question, but I was under the assumption that you wanted to control 12v from the Arduino.

Comment: i will try this